# Reading multiple lines from a text file

Tags: multithreading, file-io, text-files, large-files

I need to read a process large text files. I currently read one line at a time and process it synchronously. I need to improve performance and realise the disk access is a bottleneck. I want to refactor to have a disk read thread putting data on a queue waiting to be processed with multiple threads doing the processing. My concern is that by only reading one line at a time I might not be able to supply the data to the processing threads fast enough. Is there a way to read multiple lines on each time? I need to make sure that I don't break any words as the processing is based on words.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Many implement read-ahead automatically, so you don't need to do this. And if you use buffered I/O, you don't read a line at a time from the file, you read a large block, like 4KB.

Comment: Sounds like you want to _optimise_, not [refactor](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WhatIsRefactoring).

Comment: Why do you need to improve performance, ie. in what way(s) does the application perform poorly? Unresponsive UI? Slow throughput and available cores are unused? Other?

Comment: Yep optimise not refactor. Why? The aim is to make my program as efficient as possible. In this case that means reading and processing the text file in the smallest amount of time.

Comment: It's not clear that additional threads will speed things up, unless your text processing is _very_ CPU-expensive. This is because (a) disk speed is very much slower than CPU speed, and (b) there's also CPU overhead with threads. If you can, use a buffer of 64 KB reading from disk; this size seems to be optimal on contemporary HDDs. You could supply each thread with a buffer of up to X KB where X is 4, 8, 16, etc. and the buffer contains only whole words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whereas your program is reading one line at a time, the runtime library is reading large blocks of data from the file and then parsing the lines from a memory buffer. So when you read the first line of the file, what really happens is that the runtime library loads a large buffer, scans it to find the end of the first line, and returns that line to you. The next time you ask for a line, the runtime library doesn't have to read, but rather just find the end of the next line.

How large that buffer is depends on the runtime library, and possibly on how you initialize the file.

In addition, the file system likely maintains an even larger buffer. Your runtime library, for example, might have a 4 kilobyte file buffer, and the operating system might be buffering the input file in 64 kilobyte blocks.

In short, you probably don't need to do anything special to optimize reading the text file. You could perhaps specify a larger file buffer, and in some cases I've seen that help. Other than that, it's not worth worrying about.

Unless you have an especially fast disk subsystem, a typical developer's machine will sustain between 50 and 100 megabytes per second if you're sequentially reading line by line. In most text processing applications, that's going to be your limiting factor.